# JavaScript scoping in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
    function getData(jsonAddress) {
      var data = new Array();
      var xhr = $.getJSON(jsonAddress, function(meas) {
        for (var i = 0; i < meas.length ; i++) {
          var dt = datetimeSplitter(meas[i].valuedate);
          data[i] = [Date.UTC(dt[0],dt[1]-1,dt[2],dt[3],dt[4],dt[5]),parseInt(meas[i].value,10)];
        };
      });
      alert(data);
    }
```

I would like to make the variable "data" available to the function `getData` so I can return it (in this case alert). I understood it is a problem of scope, and can be solved with closure. I understood also what is a closure, but definitely don't know the syntax for this specific case.

Comment: The variable is available, but the `alert()` happens *before* the `$.getJSON` response comes back because `$.getJSON` is *asynchronous*. So it's not a scoping issue, it's a timing issue. Your `alert(data);` needs to be in the callback function. That's why there's a callback function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a problem of scope, it's a problem of asynchronous callbacks.

You need to pass in a callback function to this method, in order to get the response of your `getJSON()` call.

Comment: if i alert the data in the callback of the getJSON i can see that the data are retrievied, i don't know the syntax for make the variable to the upper scope, if you know the solution just write an example.

Answer (score 3):

`$.getJSON(jsonAddress, function(meas)....` is an asynchronous call i.e., alert statement will be called before the callback function (where data is set with response values) is called. If you move the alert inside the callback function, you will see that it has the correct values.

Comment: i know that but i need to call a function multiple time, and i wish there was a way for wrap it in a function.

Comment: @pm.calabrese: You'll need to learn to deal with async code. **STEP 1:** Change your function signature to this: `function getData(jsonAddress, callback) {`. **STEP 2:** Inside the callback *(after the `for` loop)*, do this: `callback(data);`. **STEP 3:** Whenever you invoke `getData()`, pass a function as the second argument, like this: `getData("http://example.com/", function(data) { alert(data); });`

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use an asynchronous call like suggested so many times before, you can also use ($.ajax)[http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/] instead - $.getJSON is just a variation of it - and make it synchronous - please be aware that this is not the advised way to do it, as your application will be blocking while the browser is synchronously retrieving the data.